# Консольное сетевое приложение

Tags: delphi, tcp-ip

Доброго времени суток! Кто пробовал работать с `indy` компонентами, в частности, с `idTCPClient` и `idTCPServer`, в консоли? Необходимо создать консольное приложение, передающее по сети файлы. Подскажите ссылками и советами...

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, не пробовал, но с расчётом на то, что это невидимые компоненты, то почему собственно и нет? Создаёшь объект

```
client := idTCPClient.Create();
```

настраиваешь свойства - и вперёд. Обработчики события тоже можно назначать программно, пример:

```
procedure MouseClick(Sender: TObject);
.....
Control.OnMouseClick := MouseClick;
```

Но вообще, если есть возможность, то лучше использовать `WinSocks`, так и быстрее и более подобающе консольному приложению будет.

Answer (score 0):

Используй `WinAPI Winsock`. Примеров в сети много.

Comment: а ссылки кто-нибудь даст?

Comment: Посмотрите http://delfcode.ru/forum/30-467-1

Comment: [и тут](http://delphisources.ru/pages/faq/internet_net.html), раздел "файлы и интернет"

Comment: А через idTCPClient, idTCPServer кто-нибудь прообовал писать консольную программу?